# How can I change the order of workspaces tabs?

Tags: interface

I want to change the order by using animation views often,

but it can't be moved to Click & Drag.

Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: Right-click and choose "reorder to front".

Comment: The UI there is very dated for... reasons and it cannot be changed easily, so you have to selectively reorder to front or back (Right click on the tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Decide which order you want your workspaces in.
2. Right-click the first (leftmost) and select `Reorder to Back`.
3. Continue the same with the next (second leftmost) workspace and so forth.

When you're done `Reorder to Back` on every workspace, they'll appear in the order you wanted.

**Tip**: Instead of having to redo this whole process when you want to insert a new workspace: Right-click on the workspace you want to precede your new workspace and choose `Duplicate`.

Comment: It was like a puzzle. Ty sir :)